# Laravel 5.7 Routing not Working for Subdomain

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-valet

For my Laravel application, I want to use subdomains to link to different spas with Vue.js. The only thing I have to do is link in the **web.php** to the **Laravel Blade file** but for some reason, it's not working.

```
<?php

Route::domain('test.mysite.test')->group(function () { 
    return view('test'); 
});
```

I run **Laravel Valet** for my virtual host. Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Have you tried to run `valet link *.mysite` within the project root directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your code like this:

```
Route::domain('test.mysite.test')->group(function () {
  Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('test');
  });
});
```

and be sure that you registered your subdomain virtual host too

Comment: This did it! Thank you very much :)